# Why does my angular 8 project does not start after install angular 10 cli?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I was working on anagular 8 project on my computer. But now need to install angular 10 t run another project.

So I have installed new version as globally: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

And the new angular 10 project works now, but angular 8 project does not start. It throws an error while starting.

> An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module
> '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package.json' Require stack:
>
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
> - C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng See "C:\Users\Mm\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-mhNKKl\angular-errors.log" for
>   further details.

My system versions are:

- npm: '6.14.6'
- Node.js v12.18.3
- Angular CLI: 10.0.8

Comment: npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular use this command

Answer (score 0):

use this command in cmd

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

Try this also

```
npm update
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not upgrade angular directly to version 10, if you are behind several versions. In your case you are at version 8 but you are going to upgrade to version 10.

In such scenario you have to upgrade to version 9 before 10.

You can find [official upgrading guide docs for the same here](https://update.angular.io/#8.0:10.0).

Comment: I am not upgrading angular 8 app to angular 10. I want to run both. Should I still do what you say?